# User Authentication state not being changed in React / Node app

Tags: reactjs, node.js, react-hooks

Im trying to authenticate a user to check if they have the required correct tokens for accessing a protected route and i dont understand why in my useEffect in my useAuth file does not correctly update the state of isAuthenticated.

here is my useAuth file

```
// useAuth.jsx file
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const useAuth = () => {
    const [isAuthenticated,setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() =>{
        const authentication = async() => {
            const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/authenticateTokens", {withCredentials: true} );
            console.log(response.data.success);
            setIsAuthenticated(response.data.success);
        }
        authentication();
    },[]);
    console.log(isAuthenticated)
    return { isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated };
};

export default useAuth;
```

my axios request above returns a json file with the value of true or false, which is consistent with what i need.

here is my PrivateRoutes file

```
import { Outlet, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import useAuth from './useAuth';


const PrivateRoutes = ({component: component, ...rest}) => {
    const {isAuthenticated} = useAuth();
    return(
        // in the ternary operation below true is first (in this case it returns the child component in the app.js file), false is second and redirects to the sign in page
        isAuthenticated ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to = "/signin"/>
    )
}

export default PrivateRoutes;
```

Comment: Needs more debug details.

Comment: `isAuthenticated` is initially false so the navigation to `"/signin"` (*and likely unmounting of `PrivateRoutes`*) occurs prior to the auth check completing.